# Dynamically add or remove views

Tags: android, android-source

For my project I need a functionality to dynamically add and remove views(textedit or buttons, etc).

I saw this similar functionality in Android "Add Contact" screen, where plus button add new fields and minus button delete the fields.

I found that `EditContactActitivity.java` is the file behind "Add Contacts".

I tried to find the methods that are called when plus or minus buttons are pressed but unable to find it, seems like "Add Contact" code is spreaded over multiple files. I am having difficulty understanding Android source code because documentation is unavailable.
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add and remove views by calling `.add()` or `.remove()` on the reference to your main layout and passing the view you wish to add or remove;

Here is a simple example of an onCreate method that demonstrates adding and removing a button:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout myMainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourMainLayout);
    Button b = new Button(this);
    //you can have some b.setXXX calls here to set text, view, click listeners etc...
    myMainLayout.add(b);



    //to remove
    myMainLayout.remove(b);

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, please can u also help me understanding android source code and getting to the particular method or function.

Answer (score -1):

I would consider researching Visibility of views rather than going through all this trouble. For example. I have an app where I have a 'record' entry screen that is relatively simple that appears as a Dialogs content. A few views/viewgroups are currently using visibility of gone, to not appear at all. If the user edits the record to add more detail, I launch an Activity that uses the same xml layout, but instantiates some of the currently 'gone' views and changes their visibility to 'visible'.

It is programmatically easy to toggle a view's visibility so I think it is really the way to go.

The only limitation I'm aware of here, would be the views order or position.